# Variable error in function called in InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, variables, innerhtml

I am new to coding, and am facing an issue calling a function from innerhtml.  I suspect the issue may be with the innerhtml syntax.
The problematic section is:

```
document.getElementById('arrowback').innerHTML = "<a href='#' onclick='return imtest(icount,imname);'><img src=/Images/ib/A2.png></a>";
```

If i change the the syntax to the below then it works for icount, which is a numeric value, not for imname:

```
document.getElementById('arrowback').innerHTML = "<a href='#' onclick='return imtest("+icount+");'><img src=/Images/ib/A2.png></a>";
```

I would like to call the imtest function with 2 variables through the innerhtml method. Below is the full code for reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clicker(buildname, imname, icount){
        var displaybox=document.getElementById('displaybox');

        if (displaybox.style.display === "none") {
            alert(imname);

            document.getElementById('imagebox').innerHTML = "<img src=" + imname + icount+".jpg height='400'>";
            document.getElementById('arrowback').innerHTML = "<a href='#' onclick= 'return imtest(icount,imname);'><img src=/Images/ib/A2.png></a>";
            document.getElementById('btitle').innerHTML = buildname;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('displaybox').style.display = "none";
        }
        return false;
    }

    function imtest(icount, imname) {
        alert(icount);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code...

**Javascript**

```
function imtest(icount, imname){
  alert("icount:" + icount + "\n imname: " + imname);
}
function clicker(buildname,imname,icount){

var displaybox=document.getElementById('displaybox');

if(displaybox.style.display == "none"){
    displaybox.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('imagebox').innerHTML = "<img src='" + imname + icount+".jpg' height='400'>";
    document.getElementById('arrowback').innerHTML = "<a onclick='return imtest(" + icount + "," + '"' + imname + '"' + ");'><img src='Images/ib/A2.png'></a>";
    document.getElementById('btitle').innerHTML = buildname;

}else{  
  document.getElementById('displaybox').style.display = "none";
}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="displaybox" style="display: none;">
  <h1 id="btitle"></h1>
  <div id="imagebox"></div>
  <div id="arrowback"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="clicker('buildname', 'imname', 'icount');">Clicker</button>
```

Comment: The section that is not working is the  onclick='return imtest(" + icount + "," + imname + "), it is not calling the imtest function that should give a basic alert when called..

Comment: No luck, it didn't work. To help narrow matters down; Whenever variable imname (string) is included in the function the code fails, however icount which is numeric works just fine. I placed alert(imname) code on the first line of the function clicker () and the variable returned with a normal string value.  after that it seems something is preventing that value from being pushed into the innerHTML element

Comment: thanks made the change to the arrowback innerhtml code as you suggested and now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add quotes around `imname`:

```
document.getElementById('imagebox').innerHTML = '<img src="' + imname + icount + '.jpg" height="400">';
document.getElementById('arrowback').innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="return imtest(' + icount + ', \"' + imname + '\");"><img src="/Images/ib/A2.png"></a>';
```

By the way, you forgot the quotes around both `src` attribute values, I've added them, and I've took the liberty of changing the quotes you use to have double quotes in your HTML.

See [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdoWbm).

Comment: look at the result of the assignment, instead of `document.getElementById('arrowback').innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="return imtest(' + icount + ', \"' + imname + '\"');"><img src="/Images/ib/A2.png"></a>';` - do `console.log('<a href="#" onclick="return imtest(' + icount + ', \"' + imname + '\"');"><img src="/Images/ib/A2.png"></a>';)` - then see if you can see why you need the quotes in the console output

Comment: Because when you output it, it's printed in the HTML. Let's say `var iname = 'abc'`. In the HTML you inject, it is now `myFunction(abc)`. When it is evaluated, it tries to find the variable "abc", which doesn't exist. Whereas with quotes around it (`myFunction("abc")`), it now has a string as an argument.

Comment: @jerska thanks I tried the above but it didn't work, function imtest still doesn't get called, are you sure about the positioning of the quotation marks?

Comment: @1dxb Can you check again? I had one extra single quote.

Comment: @Jerska made the change however it still stubbornly refuses to call the function imtest!

Comment: @1dxb Does your console output anything?

Comment: @Jerska The error in the console  is: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list1 map2.php:1:20

Comment: @1dxb I can't see any `list1` in the code you pasted. So I believe this error comes from elsewhere and isn't related to your question.

Comment: @Jerska I do not have any lists anywhere in my code as well. The code works perfectly fine with icount and uniquely fails with imname. The only difference between the 2 is that imname is a string and icount is an integer..

Comment: @1dxb http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdoWbm I confirm that it works. See [this codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdoWbm). Double click on the blue link, and the alert shows up. The error comes from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

In imtest function you are passing only one parameter and on onclick you are accepting two parameter.Check it
While accepting you shoulde write like this.

```
  document.getElementById('arrowback').innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="return imtest(' + icount + ', \"' + imname + '\"');"><img src="/Images/ib/A2.png"></a>';
```

Comment: thanks I changed the imtest function to take 2 parameters and made the changes to the arrowback innerhtml line however imtest is still not getting called.

Comment: check it with this .. (" + icount + "," + imname + ");

Comment: the above doesn't work with imname, it works fine with icount. imname is a string variable which is an image path,

Comment: You can do one more thing.                                                                           var iCountValue= document.getElementById('arrowback').innerHTML = '<a href="#" onclick="return imtest("+icount+");"><img src="/Images/ib/A2.png"></a>';                                                                              Then give alert(iCountValue);  do it same for iname with new variable..